# Maximum storage limit in QTP Array

Tags: arrays, qtp, hp-uft

What is the maximum storage level for Array in QTP/VB Script?

*** in other words, how many number of values can be stored in an array? is it infinite or we have any limitation!?

I presume there should be some limitation, so kindly let me know if anyone got to know about it.

Note: I've tried searching for some clue, but didn't get. Rather got some programs for finding maximum value in an array :P :)

Comment: Similar, with at least one reasonable, but yet no accepted, answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171522/maximum-array-of-strings-visualbasic-wsh

Answer (score 0):

It should 2gb of memory or 2.1 billion elements . All the depends on the Available system memory